# Select node covered by div attached to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div attached to the cursor, but want to select the div under it.
[image: trying to click a div under another div that's attached to the cursor]

Take that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bum9g320/2/).

I can't use the `cursor: url(...)` property, because I want to style the 'cursor'.

So how can I select the yellow div while the red one is attached to the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `pointer-events: none;` to `#bar`:

**CSS:**

```
#bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/bum9g320/4/).

Comment: Ya it's very helpful, here is an explanation on CSS-Tricks if you want to know more: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/